# Machine learning code dlib with high dimensional labels

Tags: c++, machine-learning, dlib

I am using dlib to do machine learning, but I found all the code can only deal with 1-dimensional label.

My dataset is like this: the samples are m-length vectors and the labels are n-length vectors. (m>n)

Is dlib possible to train for such dataset? If not, any suggestion of an alternative code?

Thanks.
bugspy

Comment: the problem that you mentioned is not about dlib, it is about which machine learning techniques you want to use. For instance, regression algorithms only need single label (i.e., output). So, please give more details regarding your problem so that we can point out right algorithms for you.

Comment: My problem is to use a m-length number array to predict a three component vector (e.g. 3-D velocity vector ). Is there any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is some special structure between different label types the right thing to do is to train separate models for each label.

However, if there is some special structure to your labels then you can use the [structural prediction tools](http://dlib.net/ml.html#structural_svm_problem) in dlib to handle that.  This kind of approach can handle cases where the number of possible labels is very large (e.g. 10^100000, or even infinite).  But since you said n<m then this probably isn't your problem and you should just train separate models to predict each label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's very helpful. I am doing regression. I guess structural svm can do it. I will definitely have a try.